# How to get last inserted ID to update the SAME row in a table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

How do I bring across the id so that on the second page, it will update on the same row, I keep getting errors, such as scalar variable, etc. Any help?
So, this is what I have on the first page.

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [User] (Sex,Name,DOB) VALUES(@Sex,@Name,@DOB); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";         

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", Sex);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB);

        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            int userID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close();
        }
```

this is on the second page

```
 c.CommandText = "UPDATE [User] SET Ans1 = @Ans1 WHERE Id = @id";
 c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ans1", checkboxSelection);
 c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userID);

        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            c.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close(); 
        }
```

***This is what I have now [STILL NOT WORKING]***

First page

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [User] (Sex,Name,DOB) VALUES(@Sex,@Name,@DOB); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";



        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", Sex);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB);





        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            int userID = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            Session["LastID"] = userID;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

            Con.Close();
        }
```

Second page

```
int userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LastID"]);

        c.CommandText = "UPDATE [User] SET Ans1 = @Ans1 WHERE Id = @id";

        c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ans1", checkboxSelection);
        c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userID);

        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            c.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Why you have tagged the post with `mysql` when you actually use sql server?

Comment: Sorry, will change it now, i clicked all the suggested tags

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem?

Comment: You run your query twice... Once getting the scalar and a second time saying it is a non-query. Try commenting out the second query and running it again.

Comment: My problem is this `c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userID);` userID cannot be found on the second page, how do I bring it across?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` returns an object, if you try to cast (int) you get an `Invalid Cast Exception`.
You need to:

```
    try
    {
        Con.Open();
        int userID = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
    }
```

and there is no need to call `ExecuteNonQuery` for the same command
(this will insert two records unless there is some key violation)

Then, you need to pass the `userID` to the second page.
This could achieved storing the userID in a Session variable

```
   Session["LastID"] = userID;
```

and retrieve it in the code that update the record

```
  int userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LastID"]);
```

or (as indicated in the other answer) passing it on the Redirect to the second page.

Comment: Thanks again but still unable to get it working. Would I be putting the session variable on the wrong page? Where do I put `Session["LastID"] = userID;` and `userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LastID"]);` Thanks!

Comment: The first one (write to) on the page where you insert the record (the first one) just after having retrieved the value thanks to SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY, the second one (read from) in the second page before building the parameter that require that value. You can read more about [Session here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but for the second page, it keeps giving me an error [PICTURE](http://gyazo.com/a406089ed62672ca0a22e9d7e8069c74)

Comment: The userID variable in the second page needs to be declared. It has nothing to do with the previous one (otherwise you could use its value directly without using Session). In ASP.NET every page is a different class that knows nothing of the content of previous page. Declare `int userID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["LastID"]);`

Comment: I have also fixed the answer. I thought that you had declared the userID variable before the code shown above.

Comment: Thanks @Steve I'm going to show you what I have now even though it wont work because I still don't know where to place these variables and i'm just really confused now, been stuck on this bit for too long.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51514/discussion-between-lastkingiskingin-and-steve)

Comment: After going back and doing it again, i found that it worked. Than you very much!

Answer (score 1):

On your insert page, before the end of the `try` block:

```
 Response.Redirect("SecondPage.aspx?id=" + userID.ToString());
```

And on your update page:

```
int userID;
if(int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], userID)){
    c.CommandText = "UPDATE [User] SET Ans1 = @Ans1 WHERE Id = @id";

    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ans1", checkboxSelection);
    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userID);

    try
    {
        Con.Open();
        c.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Con.Close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @onskee but why should i put the response above the try block, should I not put that underneath in the button next click? Thanks!

Comment: I had a mistake in my example, thanks for noting it.

Comment: It's ok, i'm actually still trying to figure this out, can't get it working

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to declare userID outside the try clause.
Second, the line int userID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar(); don't return an int because the command is an insert, not a select. You should rather:

```
    int userID = null;
    try
    {
        Con.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        command.CommandText = "Select Top 1 `ID` From [User] Order by `ID` desc";

        userID = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();


    }
```

Comment: Giving me error, cannot convert null to int? Thanks aswell for your answer

Comment: sorry, try int userID = 0; instead

Comment: Parts of the command text is hidden. Try to scroll right and you see the SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() that returns the just inserted ID. The ExecuteScalar call is correct.

Comment: Then the only adjustment you need to make is to take the userID variable outside the tryclause. It needs to be visible for the second page codebehind file.